# Google Map API dropdown Onchange event Listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I've a google map and i want to trigger a function whenever i select value from dynamic drop down . For that i added a listener and submitted the form like below.

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
input.setAttribute('id', 'pac-input');
input.setAttribute('class', 'controls');
input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Search By Area');

input.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    checkInputKey_map(event, $(this));
});
```

In `checkInputKey` i'm sending ajax to controller with the selected value , but in post request parameter going is not the full name which was selected . instead it's the keywords written to get the places . while i want full search names to be sent . any help will be appreciated

**update**

```
function checkInputKey_map(event,this) {
    if ((event.keyCode == 13 || event.type == 'change') && $("#API_source_map").val() == 'yelp_places') {
        searched_place = $('#pac-input').val();
        console.log(searched_place);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the `checkInputKey_map` function?

Comment: @tymeJV look at the update

Comment: Do you update the input field with the choice selected from the drop down ?

Comment: yes , but after calling the `checkinputkey_map` function and i want updated value before going into `checkinputkey_map`

Comment: could you create a small JsFiddle because it's hard to see what you mean without code.

Answer (score 1):

It feels good but annoying always to post answer to your own question . but all things apart . I made a trick and i applied the same listener to the input but with a delay of one second . My final code is like below

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('type','text');
input.setAttribute('id','pac-input');
input.setAttribute('class','controls');
input.setAttribute('placeholder','Search By Area');

input.addEventListener("change", function(event){
setTimeout(function() {
    checkInputKey_map(event, $(this));
},1000);
});
```